# NextToken not returned in boto3 kinesis List streams

Tags: boto3, amazon-kinesis

I am following this [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Paginator.ListStreams) to list my Kinesis streams . I have total of 300 plus kinesis streams and trying to use `paginator = client.get_paginator('list_streams')` to list my stream names.

This is my code

```py
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='', region_name='us-east-1')
client = session.client('kinesis')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_streams')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    PaginationConfig={
        'MaxItems': 10,
        'PageSize': 5,
    }
)
for page in response_iterator:    
    print(page)
```

but in the response I could not find `NextToken`

```
{'StreamNames': [streamnames], 'HasMoreStreams': True, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'e7e044f5-2ebd-45bd-bc07-4c724269adef', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '', 'x-amz-id-2': '', 'date': 'Thu, 10 Nov 2022 14:10:15 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '1705'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
{'StreamNames': [streamnames], 'HasMoreStreams': True, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'd9a32e03-2ab0-4edc-8244-26844664a68e', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '', 'x-amz-id-2': '', 'date': 'Thu, 10 Nov 2022 14:10:15 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '1711'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [paginator docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html), you don't actually need to use the `NextToken`. Eg, you're using it correctly already.

See example code from above docs:

```
import boto3

# Create a client
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')

# Create a reusable Paginator
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')

# Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket')

for page in page_iterator:
    print(page['Contents'])
```

Further clarification from a [github issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3460#issuecomment-1284709551) from one of the boto3 contributors.

Comment: I don't understand, I have 300 + kinesis streams and I need to paginate by having 10 as MaxItems and 5 per page. How do I retrieve remaining streams?

Comment: Do you get the expected results when using the aws cli? `aws kinesis list-streams`

Comment: it works fine when I don't use any config `response_iterator = client.get_paginator('list_streams').paginate()` but problem happens only when I specify ` 'MaxItems': 10, 'PageSize': 5,`

Comment: yeah works fine with aws cli

Comment: Strange, try adding a `'StartingToken': None` variable in your request too? If not, I'd raise a bug